# The way angular bootstraps

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a question about the way Angular bootstraps. Consider this directive:

```
app.directive('finder', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<div><input type="text" data-ng-model="my-input" style="width:80%;" /></div>',
        compile: function (element, attributes) {
            if (attributes.hasOwnProperty('required')) {
                element.removeAttr('required');
                element.find(':input').attr('required', true);
                element.removeClass("ng-invalid ng-invalid-required");
            }
            return {
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, attributes) {
                    // Do some other stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And I use this directive as follows:

```
<div>
  <finder required></finder>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
.ng-invalid-required {
  background: yellow;
}
```

As you can see in the directive, in the compile phase, I remove the `required` attribute from the element and add the attribute to the `input` element. The result is what you (sort of) should expect: the main element doesn't have the attribute anymore, but the input field does.

Now the 'strange' part: The output shows that the div also has a yellow background. As it turns out, the main element (div) has the `ng-invalid-required` class! This is strange because I removed the `required` attribute in the compile phase...

How is this possible?

Apparently, Angular scans the whole DOM for directives and collect the directives with the belonging elements. After the scan, Angular is going to compile all the directives. At one point it is going to compile my `finder` directive. This directive removes the required attribute and add it to my input field. Later on it compiles the required attribute. Because the 'original element' is in the collected list it is going to add the `ng-invalid-required` class to the linked element (the div).

Is this correct? Or is there another explanation for this behaviour?

EDIT (thanks to Nikos Paraskevopoulos suggestion in his comment).
Interesting: When I add this to the directive:

```
 priority: 1000,
 terminal: true
```

It works like I would expect. But when I leave one of those properties, it doesn't work anymore. Could someone explain to me why this works?

Comment: Some guesses, since I haven't tried this: Have you tried to specify a `priority` on your directive, so that it compiles *before* `ng-required` and also setting your directive to `terminal: true`, so that nothing else executes after it?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Thanks, when I use both properties it works. Could you explain why(/how) this works?

Comment: Hi, moved the comment to answer and added explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moved from comment to answer + explanation)

Try specifying both `priority` (to a value so that your directive runs before the `requiredDirective`) and `terminal: true` in your directive definition.

**Explanation:**

The reason for the original problem is that the `requiredDirective` executes on the element. Obviously, as you point out, Angular scans the whole DOM for directives and collects the directives *and executes them*. To clarify: first it collects them, then executes them.

This means that the `requiredDirective` will execute despite your `compile()` function having removed the `required` attribute, because Angular has already "collected" the directives.

The `terminal: true` property:

> If set to true then the current priority will be the last set of directives which will execute

This means that if you set priority to a value so that your directive executes *before* the `requiredDirective`, the latter will not execute at all! Obviously, Angular *stops* the collection of directives when it encounters one with `terminal: true`.

Answer (score 1):

"required" is compiled before your element, so I think that even if you remove required attribute it was already marked as required and angularjs adds ng-invalid class.

Try to change the priority of your directive to 1000, so it will be compiled before required directive and so you can remove required attribute:

```
app.directive('finder', function () {
  return {
    priority: 100,
    restrict: 'E',
    ...
  };
});
```

Comment: This doen't work, I also have to add `terminal: true` to get everything to work. Could you explain why this is?

Comment: In my example, I put 100, but you must to try with 1000. If you add terminal:true, so angularjs will not compile child elements of your element. For example, if you have <finder><div ng-show="foo"></div></finder>, so angularjs will not compile your div and its ng-show attribute.